# PDF file won't open in browser with headers

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers

After many posts, I successfully managed to create htaccess and validation file to handle PDF calls via URL.

The problem is, script doesn't output PDF file. It read as "The PDF document might not be displayed correctly" in Firefox and no error in Chrome, it just doesn't do anything.

Any idea why?

Thanks

**Note:** PDF files exist in the folder. I can open them directly after disabling htaccess.

**validation.php**

```
session_start();

//If user not logged in or URL not set then redirect to login page
if (! isset($_SESSION['user']) || ! isset($_GET['request_url']))
{
    session_write_close();

    header ('Location: /login.php');
    exit();
}
//Otherwise
else
{
    //Get request URL from htaccess
    $request_url = $_GET['request_url'];
    //Get file name only
    $filename = basename($request_url);

    //Set headers
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($request_url));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    //Output file content
    @readfile($request_url);

    //Take the log
    $file = 'log.txt';
    $log  = file_get_contents($file);
    $log .= 'URL:' . $request_url . ' - FILE:' . $filename . ' - TIMESTAMP:' . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "\n";

    @file_put_contents($file, $log);
}
```

**HTACCESS:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /validate.php?request_url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with absolute path.

Replace

```
@readfile($request_url);
```

With

```
@readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $request_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@` from this line:

```
@readfile($request_url);
```

and see what error you get.

`file_put_contents()` has optional FILE_APPEND flag, you don't have to read in the content of the log

```
$file = 'log.txt';
$log = 'URL:' . $request_url . ' - FILE:' . $filename . ' - TIMESTAMP:' . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "\n";
@file_put_contents($file, $log, FILE_APPEND);
```